# TensorFlow Lite for ARM - Cortex M

Tags: deep-learning, arm, tensorflow-lite, cortex-m

I’d like to ask if there is TensorFlow Lite that should run ML models on mobile, embedded, and edge devices available for microcontrollers having cores: ARM Cortex M7, ARM Cortex M55/M33?

If not, what does not allow to have TF-Lite even for Cortex M7/M55/M33 that are fast-clocked in the GHz range?

Is it possible to run TF-Lite for a bare-metal (No-OS) environment or it only runs with OS-system (Linux)?
Do its microcontroller-optimized Tensorflow-Micro only targets this microcontroller domain (bare-metal, RTOS)?

If there is no TF-Lite available for Cortex M7/M55/M33, does it TF-Micro can run floating point ML models?

Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842663/operations-calculator-for-image-processing

Comment: since you don't have the ["informed" badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) yet, and you haven't accepted any answer on your 52 questions so far, please take the [tour]

Answer (score -1):

Makers of ARM Cortex M/A controllers may provide you with a library/framework to do inferencing on their devices, optimized specifically for ARM Cortex M/A.

Do NOT expect any performance out a random Cortex M. They may not have "DSP"/vector instructions.

Forget floating point. There are optimizers for neural networks that break them down to fixed point/integer operations. That's the only kind you want on an embedded device.

Comment: So I asked about the TF-Lite specifically, and its usage for microcontrollers.